# Where is GRUB's boot information located? (want to delete partition)

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have a laptop with two internal storages.

- M.2 SSD: Windows/Ubuntu
- HDD: Debian/DATA

4 partitions in total.

I used to boot mainly from Debian and sometimes from Windows. After some time I made space and installed Ubuntu along Windows, but put the boot stuff in the HDD (I was afraid to mess with the Windows installation).

So, at boot, the HDD is accessed first, and a GRUB menu pops up with the options Debian/Ubuntu. When I want to boot Windows, I just press F12 and enter boot selection and go directly to the M.2 SSD where Windows is (which has no Debian boot info).

If I delete the Debian partition, is the GRUB boot information gone? Or can I just get rid of it and run `update-grub` from Ubuntu?

Alternatively, how could I transfer Ubuntu boot to the SSD along Windows? (and give up booting from the HDD entirely).

Maybe I'm being too careful. But just don't want to go on and assume that all the boot information is outside the original partition of the OS that actually created it.

Answer (score 2):

### Don't Just Delete the OS

Yes if you delete you will most likely delete critical grub information and cause problems. Grub has three critical parts:

1. A stub installed in either the [MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record), or a file on the EFI partition (`/boot/efi`).
2. Configuration files and modules typically found on your Linux partition under `/boot/grub`
3. Configuration generator scripts typically found in `/etc/grub.d` which generally rely on a bunch of other scripts and binaries located on your Linux system.

A standard Debian or Ubuntu install will often have `/boot/grub` on the main partition meaning that if you delete your OS you trash grub.

However if I read correctly then you have Windows, Debian and Ubuntu and you want to scrap only Debian, keeping Windows and Ubuntu.  You could just  use Ubuntu's instance of grub since both Debian and Ubuntu will both have installed their own.

## Can files be moved?

If using EFI, you can just copy the files from the EFI partition on one hard drive to the partition on another.  Likewise you can create a partition for `/boot/grub` files on the SSD.  After doing so you will need to re-configure your BIOS so that it boots the correct thing first.

Keeping the bootloader stub (1) and grubs config and modules (2) is enough to boot, but you'll have a hard time re-configuring grub if you lose the config generators (3).  This means that while it's possible to use grub without *nix to configure it for you, you don't really want to.

Also if you are booting with Legacy then moving grub entirely onto the SSD will mean overwriting the Windows bootloader on the MBR.  Many people have done this and we often see their crys for help here.

## Switching to Ubuntu's grub if you are booting legacy (MBR)

Under Ubuntu run:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
sudo update-grub
```

where /dev/sda is your HDD NOT your SSD.

This will set Ubuntu's grub instance to the active boot-loader

## Switching to Ubuntu's grub if you are booting with EFI:

Under Ubuntu first check that you have Ubuntu's boot-loader installed correctly:

```
sudo ls /boot/efi/EFI/Ubuntu
fbx64.efi  grub.cfg  grubx64.efi  mmx64.efi  shimx64.efi
```

If Ubuntu's EFI directory is missing then create it by running:

```
sudo grub-install
sudo update-grub
```

Then reboot and go into your BIOS settings.  Look under your boot options, check to see if you can select Ubuntu to boot first.  You might need to tell your BIOS about the newly installed boot-loader in EFI.

BIOS options vary a lot so I can't tell you how to do this.